# mp3 file is not playing automatically when the page loads

Tags: html, audio

I want an mp3 file to play automatically when the page loads, but that doesn't happen.. the file only plays when I press the play button.. how do I get it to play automatically?

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="muzic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <p>If you can read this, your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

It works with another browser, but is there any way to make autoplay work in Chrome?

Comment: Many browsers have disallowed this. Check your *browser's* settings and rules. Most users find this annoying which is way it is being disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other browsers?

This should help
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support this feature because the code you have written is correct. However, there is another javascript trick that can be used I will suggest you try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay mode should be added to the opening tag of your code, this is widely supported by Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change that mpeg to mp3. Just like this:

`<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="muzic.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  <p>If you can read this, your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>`
it will work

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that could be wrong. 
1) your browser doesn’t support it 
2) your file format “mpeg” should be “mp3”